# Multiple formula in a cell with number formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello everyone and thank you for your time, I have this formula in a cell:
="Between "&A5*0.95&" And "&A5*1.05

but I get a long number with decimal points, how do I add this number format in the above formula, I tried everywhere but it keeps giving errors:  #,##0

The result I'm looking for is something like: Between 4,002 And 204

Thanking you in advance

Comment: `A50.95` is not a cell reference. Check how to use `TEXT` function

Comment: Thank you so much David, the formula below worked perfectly:

Comment: ="Between "& TEXT(A6*0.95,"#,##0")&"  and  "&TEXT(A6*1.05,"#,##0")